# Best statistical hand

Tags: texas-hold-em

Heads-up.

Player 1 has K♥ Q⋄

Player 2 has 4♥ and 3♥

On the board: Q♥ 5♠ 6♥ 3⋄

Which player has the best statistical hand in this situation?

Comment: @**Vayreda** use Equilab app or other alternative apps to count equity
manual operations are inefficient and troublesome so make automation

Comment: @Grisza There is one card left.  Counting outs and making the calculation is very easy and efficient.    And it is something you need to do at the table  in your head to to be profitable.

Answer (score 3):

- Player 1 K:hearts:Q:diamonds:
- Player 2 4:hearts:3:hearts:
- board  Q:hearts:6:hearts:5:spades:3:diamonds:

Player 1 is ahead with a pair of queens

Player 2 has pair of 3s and must improve to win
52 - 8 = 44 cards out
a flush, straight, pair, or trips for player 2 to improve
8 hearts + 6 straight + 3 pair + 2 trips = 19 outs

**Player 2 win** = 19/44 = **0.4318**

**Player 1 win** = 1 - 19/44 = **0.5682**

Answer (score 1):

Player 1 has a pair of Queens and is ahead.

Player 2 has a pair of 3s, is four to a heart flush, and has an open-ended straight draw.

Player 2 has 19 outs (8 cards can make the flush, 6 will complete the straight, three possibilities to make two paid, 2 possibilities to make trips).

8 cards are known, leaving 44 cards unknown.  19 of these cards will give player 2 the win, the rest will result in player 1 winning.

Player 1 chance of winning: 56.8%

Player 2 chance of winning: 43.2%

Comment: Wrong number of outs.  You are double counting 2 on straight - flush.